# I have the exact same functions and logic for different divs and CSS changes, but it only applies to some

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what the log-in form and the script for changing the CSS based on whether the field is empty or not look like:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('forma');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const lozinka = document.getElementById('lozinka');
const faliemail = document.getElementById('faliemail');
const falilozinka = document.getElementById('falilozinka');


form
  .addEventListener(
    'submit',
    (event) => {
      email.classList.toggle('error', !email.validity.valid);
      lozinka.classList.toggle('error', !lozinka.validity.valid);
      faliemail.classList.toggle('promeni', !email.validity.valid);
      falilozinka.classList.toggle('promeni', !lozinka.validity.valid);

      if (!email.validity.valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }


      if (!lozinka.validity.valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  );

email
  .addEventListener(
    'input',
    () => {
      email.classList.toggle('uredu', email.validity.valid);
    }
  );

lozinka
  .addEventListener(
    'input',
    () => {
      lozinka.classList.toggle('uredu', lozinka.validity.valid);
    }
  );
```

```css
#faliemail {
  display: none;
}

#falilozinka {
  display: none;
}

#lozinka.error {
  border: 2px solid #eb7178;
}

#email.error {
  border: 2px solid #eb7178;
}

#faliemail.promeni {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#faliemail.promeni h5 {
  color: #eb7178;
}

#falilozinka.promeni {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#falilozinka.promeni h5 {
  color: #eb7178;
}

#email.uredu {
  border: none;
}

#lozinka.uredu {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="container" method="post" action="" id="forma" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
  <h3>Email*</h3>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input" placeholder="Email" required>

  <div id="faliemail">
    <h5 class="crvena">Unesi email</h5>
  </div>

  <h3>Lozinka*</h3>
  <input type="password" name="lozinka" id="lozinka" class="input" placeholder="Šifra" required>

  <div id="falilozinka">
    <h5 class="crvena">Unesi lozinku</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="buttoncontainer">
    <button class="button" name="button" id="button" type="submit">Prijavi se</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I go to the sign-up page though, it doesn't quite work the same. Here's that form and the script:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('formareg');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const lozinka = document.getElementById('lozinka');
const ime = document.getElementById('ime');
const prezime = document.getElementById('prezime');

form
  .addEventListener(
    'submit',
    (event) => {
      ime.classList.toggle('error', !ime.validity.valid);
      prezime.classList.toggle('error', !prezime.validity.valid);
      email.classList.toggle('error', !email.validity.valid);
      lozinka.classList.toggle('error', !lozinka.validity.valid);
      faliemail.classList.toggle('promeni', !email.validity.valid);
      falilozinka.classList.toggle('promeni', !lozinka.validity.valid);
      faliime.classList.toggle('promeni', !ime.validity.valid);
      faliprezime.classList.toggle('promeni', !prezime.validity.valid);

      if (!ime.validity.valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      if (!prezime.validity.valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }


      if (!email.validity.valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      if (!lozinka.validity.valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

    }
  );

ime
  .addEventListener(
    'input',
    () => {
      ime.classList.toggle('uredu', ime.validity.valid);
    }
  );

prezime
  .addEventListener(
    'input',
    () => {
      prezime.classList.toggle('uredu', prezime.validity.valid);
    }
  );

email
  .addEventListener(
    'input',
    () => {
      email.classList.toggle('uredu', email.validity.valid);
    }
  );

lozinka
  .addEventListener(
    'input',
    () => {
      lozinka.classList.toggle('uredu', lozinka.validity.valid);
    }
  );
```

```css
#ime.uredu {
  border: none;
}

#ime.error {
  border: 2px solid #eb7178;
}

#prezime.uredu {
  border: none;
}

#prezime.error {
  border: 2px solid #eb7178;
}

#faliime {
  display: none;
}

#faliime.promeni {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#faliime.promeni h5 {
  color: #eb7178;
}

#faliprezime {
  display: none;
}

#faliprezime.promeni {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#faliprezime.promeni h5 {
  color: #eb7178;
}
```

```html
<form class="container" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" id="formareg" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
  <h3>Ime*</h3>
  <input type="text" name="ime" id="ime" class="input" placeholder="Ime" required>

  <div id="faliime">
    <h5 class="crvena">Unesi ime</h5>
  </div>

  <h3>Prezime*</h3>
  <input type="text" name="prezime" id="prezime" class="input" placeholder="Prezime" required>

  <div id="faliprezime">
    <h5 class="crvena">Unesi prezime</h5>
  </div>

  <h3>Email*</h3>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input" placeholder="Email" required>

  <div id="faliemail">
    <h5 class="crvena">Unesi email</h5>
  </div>

  <h3>Lozinka*</h3>
  <input type="password" name="lozinka" id="lozinka" class="input" placeholder="Šifra" required>

  <div id="falilozinka">
    <h5 class="crvena">Unesi lozinku</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="buttoncontainerreg">
    <button class="button2b" name="button2b" type="submit" onclick="predajKorisnika();">Registruj se</button>
  </div>

  <div class="prikazilink" id="prikazilink">
    <a href="prijava.php" class="reroute" id="link">
      <p>Već imaš nalog? Prijavi se
        <p>
    </a>
    <div>
</form>
```

The log-in form works in a way where when I submit the form with the empty fields, I get the `falilozinka` and `faliemail` divs get displayed and the input fields get the red border. As soon as I type in something, the fields start to change and the border disappears. I have one more form on my website that also works the same.

The problem is in the sign-up, or the second form I included. The `email` and `lozinka` fields work as they should. I have the problem with `ime` and `prezime` fields. They work properly with submitting, where only the empty ones will become red, but when I try to type something inside them, the border remains red and I can't figure out why that is. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `.error` to the `#email input` but you don't have a style. Change

```
#ime.error {
  border: 2px solid #eb7178;
}

#prezime.error {
  border: 2px solid #eb7178;
}
```

to

```
.error {
  border: 2px solid #eb7178;
}
```

...and it will style it correctly. I would also suggest to use `outline` instead of `border` so things don't jump around more than necessary.

At the same time, change

```
#faliime.promeni h5 {
  color: #eb7178;
}

#faliprezime.promeni h5 {
  color: #eb7178;
}
```

to

```
h5.crvena {
  color: #eb7178;
}
```

Comment: @MihailoMitrović No worries. I added some text about the error message as well.